# Post Creators Update: Modifying Windows 10 window border color w/o changing accent colors

Tags: windows-10, colors, windows-10-v1703

The border color of Windows 10 windows defaults to the accent color selected in Settings > Personalization > Colors. It may be desirable to change the border color to match the title bar color -- if it's different from the accent color -- or because the accent color doesn't look appropriate on window borders. Changing the accent color to modify the border color would cause similar issues with the start menu. Thus, the need to configure the start menu color and border color separately.

This used to be somewhat possible by using [Color and Appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhb0i.png),

[image]

and tweaking Brightness/Saturation/Intensity as the start menu ignored these values pre Creators Update while window borders didn't. However, now Microsoft gives more control over the accent color, so the start menu began taking these values into account as well.

The registry may be here to save the day though. Navigating to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`, we find `ColorizationColor`. Modifying this changes the window border color once the user logs out and then back in. *However*, whenever the UAC pops up (and perhaps various other triggers), the border color is reset to the accent color. The value of `ColorizationColor` does not change, but the border color does, and it does not revert back.

Is there, by chance, some way to prevent the border color from being reset once UAC opens (e.g. by running a program as an admin), or to manually tweak the color of the start menu so that I can configure border color and start menu color separately?