# Why are my Windows border frames pink?

Tags: windows-10, colors

So lately, I've been noticing pink borders and areas (in Photo Viewer) in Windows 10. I don't know why. You can see I've posted my settings, and the top is orangish as it should be, but then the sides and bottom are pink.
[image]
And I've just noticed posting this, Firefox has a complete pink border as well.

The other day, I noticed Windows Photo Viewer's base went pink as well. That's what originally made me notice this. Maybe it's the issue? (Not Photo Viewer, but it's proving something is weird.)
[image]

What have I done, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it since the Creators Update? Perhaps the suggestion here is related: https://superuser.com/questions/1197905/post-creators-update-modifying-windows-10-window-border-color-w-o-changing-acce?rq=1

Comment: How did you achieve black background color? It could be related, too.

Comment: @Ashton: I don't see anything related. I had "automatically pick an accent" by default, and changed it. It didn't change anything.
miroxlav: Originally, I let Windows pick the settings based on my background. That's how it was.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you're having the high contrast theme active. Try pressing Alt+Shift+Print to toggle it. In case the hotkey does not work, search for High Contrast in your Windows settings and toggle it there.